# How Fragment can get data from MainActivity class that getting data using http and asycn task?

Tags: android, http, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm creating an Android App using Android Studio. I'm using Navigation Drawer template. I want to show data from web using http and async task in home fragment. I copy paste code of class from the internet that fetch data from web.

This is the class :

```
    class FetchThingspeakTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetching Data from Server.Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=I9CEDD46LZX2HZTC");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
 // I want to get this response and use it in any fragment
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I put that class in MainActivity.java and execute that in main activity. I execute this class every one minute using timer and handler.

I actually get the response but the response is not usable in fragment. I want to take data from the class that call API and giving response in all fragments.

this is full main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        setRepeatingAsyncTask();

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    class FetchThingspeakTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetching Data from Server.Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels.json?api_key=I9CEDD46LZX2HZTC");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            // I want to get this response and use it in any fragment
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void setRepeatingAsyncTask() {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            new FetchThingspeakTask().execute();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 0, 60*1000);  // interval of one minute

    }
}
```

Is there any suggest how to do that ?

Update:

I want this response will dynamically update in fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare global variable for fragment

```
Fragment fragmentRef = new MyFragment() // your fragment name
```

Now Inside onPostExecute()

For the very first API call, make your fragment transaction means inflate fragment from activity

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragmentRef, "TAG).commit()
```

make **setData()** method in fragment  and call using fragmentRef

```
fragmentRe.setData(response) //pass your data
```

Now for next/subsequent API calls, check and get your fragment from fragmentManager by using findFragmentByTag() , once you get fragment reference, then call **setData()** Method

```
if( fragmentRef !=null){
    fragmentRef.setData(response)
  }
```